# How to SCP a file from a different Partition of my system

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, scp

I have a dual os machine(windows and ubuntu). I am currently using ubuntu and I want to copy a file from my machine to another.
To do that I used the following command:

```
scp /path/to/file user@xx.xxx.x.xxx:
```

This works since my file is in ubuntu.

Is that possible to copy a file/folder from windows as well? from ubuntu terminal?

Comment: If you really have a dual boot machine, there is always only one of the systems running. In Ubuntu you can mount the Windows filesystem and copy files to and from this filesystem. On the other hand Windows does not know the ext4 filesystem (generally used in ubuntu) so the other way round will not go. If you want to access both file systems in parallel you have to install some kind of virtual machine (VirtualBox, VMware, ...).

Comment: Yes, in windows you can use winscp program. You can also install Samba on the linux machine and access your windows shares. You can also pull the file from windows while at the ubuntu machine command line. You share a folder on windows in the normal way and mount it on your Ubuntu machine. EXAMPLE "mount -t cifs //192.168.10.10/myshare /mnt -o username=victor'. Then cp /mnt/thefile /home/victor/desktop.

Comment: Currently I am manually copying file from the device and pasting it in my ubuntu home and then doing the scp command. If we can access the device from files->devices->xx GB Volume(user interface), Can't we access the same device from the terminal? Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: OK think I misunderstood. You want to copy a file from your windows partition. Yes you can, just mount it first. Example.  If windows is on your second partition "mount /dev/sda2 /mnt." Then "scp /mnt/path/to/file user@destination" etc